# Optimizing a dataframe subset operation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, bioinformatics

Summarize the Problem

I am trying to optimize some code I have written. In its current form it works as intended, however because of the sheer number of loops required the script it takes a very long time to run.

I'm looking for a method of speeding up the below-described code.

Detail the problem

Within this data frame called master, there are 3,936,192 rows. The Position column represents a genomic window. Which is present in this data frame 76 times. Such that `master[master['Position'] == 300]` returns a dataframe of 76 rows, and similar for each unique appearance of Position. I do some operations on each of these subsets of the data frame.

The data can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3sksk3vp63bnf61/master.csv?dl=0)

My current code takes the form:

```py
import pandas as pd

master = pd.read_csv(data_location)

windows = sorted(set(master['Position']))

window_factor = []

               # loop through all the windows, look at the cohort of samples, ignore anything not CNV == 2
               # if that means ignore all, then drop the window entirely
               # else record the 1/2 mean of that windows normalised coverage across all samples. 

for window in windows:
    current_window = master[master['Position'] == window]

    t = current_window[current_window['CNV'] == 2]

    if t.shape[0] == 0:
        window_factor.append('drop')

    else:
        window_factor.append(
            np.mean(current_window[current_window['CNV'] == 2]['Normalised_coverage'])/2)
```

However, this takes an exceptionally long time to run and I can't figure out a way to speed this up, though I know there must be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think .groupby() function is what you need here:

```
fac = []
for name,group in master.groupby('Position'):
    if all(group['CNV'] != 2):
        fac.append('drop')
    else:
        fac.append(np.mean(group[group['CNV'] == 2]['Normalised_coverage'])/2)
```

I downloaded your data master.csv, data generated is exactly the same, running time decreased from 6 min to 30 sec on my laptop.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

your `df` is not that big and in your code there are few problems:

- If you use `np.mean` and  one value is `np.nan` it returns `np.nan`
- You can divide by 2 after calculate the mean.
- It seems to me a perfect case for `groupby`
- Return a string while other results are `float` you might consider to use 
  `np.nan` instead

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("master.csv")

def fun(x):
    t = x[x["CNV"]==2]
    return t["Normalised_coverage"].mean()/2

# returns np.nan when len(t)==0
out = df.groupby('Position').apply(fun)
CPU times: user 34.7 s, sys: 72.5 ms, total: 34.8 s
Wall time: 34.7 s
```

Or even faster filtering before the `groupby` as

```py
%%time
out = df[df["CNV"]==2].groupby("Position")["Normalised_coverage"].mean()/2

CPU times: user 82.5 ms, sys: 8.03 ms, total: 90.5 ms
Wall time: 87.8 ms
```

**UPDATE:** In the last case if you really need to keep track of groups where `df["CNV"]!=2` you can use this code:

```py
import numpy as np
bad = df[df["CNV"]!=2]["Position"].unique()
bad = list(set(bad)-set(out.index))

out = out.reset_index(name="value")

out1 = pd.DataFrame({"Position":bad,
                     "value":[np.nan]*len(bad)})

out = pd.concat([out,out1],
                ignore_index=True)\
        .sort_values("Position")\
        .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which is going to add `160ms` to your computation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do several things:

- instead of using a python list for window_factor consider using a np.array since
  you know the length of the array.
- `t` is already `current_window[current_window['CNV'] == 2]` use `t` when calculate np.mean.

You can also use a profiler to see if there are operations that are expensive, or just consider using C++ and reimplement the code(it's very simple).

Answer (score 0):

Using groupby and query was the solution I went with.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

master = pd.read_csv("/home/sean/Desktop/master.csv", index_col=0)

windows = sorted(set(master['Position']))

g = master.groupby("Position")

master.query("Position == 24386700").shape

g = master.query("CNV == 2").groupby("Position")

p = g.Normalised_coverage.mean() / 2
```